# Xamarin can't see objects in MainPage.xaml from MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I can't see my label or button from my MainPage.xaml.cs. if I try this line in my MainPage.xaml.cs

valueLabel.text = "Hi";

in the error list the error valuelabel does not exists in current content

I have tried in days to fix this but can't find a solution, hope you can help me

my code:

My MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:knap_der_tæller_op"
         x:Class="knap_der_tæller_op.MainPage">

<Label x:Name="valueLabel"
   Text="A simple Label"
   Font="Large"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
<Button Text="Click Me!"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />

</ContentPage>
```

My MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace knap_der_tæller_op
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

    }
    void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }
    public string Labettext { get; set; } = "Hej med dig" ;
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you try the code `valueLabel.Text = "Hi";`

Comment: try to create using available xamarin forms template instead of blank app

Comment: And you have to layout your components using stacklayout or grid or other layout. sometimes you have to rebuild before call your components from code behind, because sometimes its not automatically updated

Comment: I tried the valueLabel.Text = "Hi"; in the onbuttonclicked. 
I works when i'm generating a template, but when i make a blank to make my own project it fails :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the content in a `<ContentPage.Content></ContentPage.Content>`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to rebuild your project and the problem is solved

Comment: for this kind of answer, you can just add it to the comment section. not give it as the answer.